# Reference Missing After Nuget Package Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget

I want to start off by saying I've been really hesitant to ask this question because it seems like it should be such a simple thing, however, I've scoured the internet and all I can find is the basic solution to something similar to my issue.

I have a nuget package that is v 1.30 and I'm trying to update it to 1.41. I've used the NuGet UI and I've also used the Package Manager Console to do this multiple times with small variations and I continue to get the same result. After I do something like "Update-Package PackageName" my package updates correctly. NuGet deletes the old reference and the old files and the 1.41 version is referenced by all the projects in the solution using that package. When I look at the Code, there are no syntax errors, Visual Studio seems to think the reference is just fine and I can even ctrl+B (re#er) to 'go to declaration.' However, when I build, every place I have 'using PackageName' in code throws an error that says

```
"The type or namespace name 'Common' does not exist in the namespace 'PackageName' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"
```

I have tried cleaning my solution. Then building. I've tried resetting through Git, cleaning the solution, updating then building. I've tried updating, cleaning, deleting the reference, building (will get the errors obviously), then adding the reference back in manually and building. Every time I try I get the same error. It's only happening for my Core project, but all my other projects depend on the Core, so they won't build anyway. I'm assuming this issue would still present itself if they were able to build. I've looked at the properties of the reference, it is referencing the v 1.41 file and it is set to Copy Local = True (I read somewhere someone suggested looking at that).

I'm open to suggetions for things to try. I don't have any code changes that I'll lose of I do a Git Reset, so I can try whatever.

Thanks Internet.

Comment: More likely than not, the upgraded version shuffled around the namespaces it uses: namely, removing `Common`. However, since you haven't told us what package this is, there's no way to confirm that. This is why you shouldn't upgrade packages unless you know what those updates entail and what, if any, changes you will need to make to your application. Always read the release notes.

Comment: did you restart VS of restart PC, could help.. but like Chis states.. we dont know what Common is.

Comment: @ChrisPratt sorry, forgot to include, it's an internal nuget package we have hosted on our internal nuget server, which is why I didn't bother with putting up what the package name is. I actually made the update to that package and Common is definitely not missing or shuffled. The structure of that particular solution hasn't changed since its inception.

Comment: You can always downgrade by removing the package, and then installing the specific version you need: `Install-Package PackageName -Version 1.3.0`. You can also prevent packages from updating past certain versions if you want to avoid automatic updates: http://docs.nuget.org/create/versioning#Constraining_Upgrades_To_Allowed_Versions

Comment: @lordkain I did restart VS multiple times, one try was between cleaning the solution and updating the package

Comment: You mentioned removing and re-adding references. I'm assuming you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the full package?

Comment: @ChrisPratt I might get to the point where I do that, I'm hoping to avoid it though because there are several packages I have installed that depend on that package. It's a little convoluted. Common contains tools that we use through pretty much all of our apps, hence the name Common. It's also used in some of our other internal nuget packages. Makes things really painful though if we get to a spot where we need to uninstall something like Common because of this issue.

Comment: If you use the `-Force` directive, only the specific package will be removed, regardless of what depends on it, i.e. `uninstall-package PackageName -Force`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Tried uninstalling like that. Didn't work. The crazy thing is I can build and get all those errors, then I can go do the code, removing the using statements and where I get a syntax error in code, use resharper to create the using statement, which fixes the syntax errors, but causes the build to still have the same errors. I'm thinking now there might be something weird going on with that package, although it seems to be just fine since the structure is unchanged.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Figured it out. Framework mismatch from a previous update to the package I hadn't been made aware of. It would be nice if the build errors could be a bit more relevant in that scenario :D. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

After trying several different things, we figured out it was a version mismatch with ASP.NET. Someone had pulled in a newer package that required updating to ASP.NET 4.5 and the solution I was working in was still ASP.NET 4.0. After updating to 4.5 the problem with the references was resolved. But we ran into some new Automapper issues. One thing after another. However, if you're banging your head against your desk in frustration because of this problem, check the framework version of your projects and the package you're updating.